# EF Core 7 - How to add a navigation property without the pulling the actual entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to synchronize a external database with my app database. For this task I added a `Adapter` which fetches updates from the `ExternalRepo` and adds them to my `AppContext`.

Because the `ExternalRepo` has no access to the `AppContext` I need to instantiate a new `Employee` for the navigation property of the `Order` class. Since the same (already existing) `Employee` can be on multiple `Order`'s the `context.SaveChanges` throws an error.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem or improve this design would be appreciated!

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Employee Employee {get;set;}
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get;set}
}

public class ExternalRepo
{
    public List<Order> FetchOrders(int projectId)
    {
        var orders = new List<Order>();

        // Fetch from external databse

        orders.Add(new Order()
        {
            Id = sqlReader["orderId"],
            Employee = new Employee() { Id = sqlReader["employeeId"] }
        });

        // Since the ExternalRepo doesnt have access to the context I cannot pull the existing employee
        // So if there are multiple orders with the same Employee I get an error when saving the changes to the context
        
        return orders;
    }
}

public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Project> Projects {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
}

public class Adapter 
{
    private ExternalRepo external;
    private AppContext context;

    public void Update(int projectId)
    {
        var project = context.Projects.Find(projectId);
        var updates = external.FetchOrders(projectId);

        foreach(var update in updates)
        {
            if(!project.Orders.Any(x => x.Id == update.Id))
                project.Orders.Add(update);
        }

        // this throws 'The instance of type "Employee" cannot be tracked beacause another instance with the same key ...
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

At first I had the `Adapter` directly accessing the external database without the `ExternalRepo`. This worked because I could pull the `Employee` from the `AppContext` within the call to the database. But I wanted to separate the classes and included the `ExternalRepo`

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of trouble by adding an `EmployeeId` property to `Order`.

Comment: What if the `Employee` class hold more properties? If I want to fetch the whole `Project` entity then there would be multiple database calls needed since I cannot use `Include(x => x.Employee)`.
Would the performance impact be noticeable when working with large datasets?

Comment: ORMs in general are *not* meant for ETL or data synchronization. They're meant to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables. In a sync job the "objects" are Table, Row, Query, LastSyncVersion. An ORM like EF Core offers nothing but does add a lot of delays by caching data in memory and mapping it twice when there's probably no need for any mapping

Comment: If you have a way of tracking changes in the remote database, eg using SQL Server's Change Tracking, a sequential ID or, worse case, `Created` and `Updated` columns, you can retrieve all rows added since the last sync and insert them directly to the target. That requires running a query that returns a DbDataReader and inserting those rows to the target. If you use SQL Server, you can use the SqlBulkCopy class to insert the data using minimal logging. For updates, you can insert them into a staging table then UPDATE the final table. That's how eg SSIS works